# parse string and send as Json in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have real big problem finding the right code which helps me to parse String to JSON and then send to external server. I'm using xCode 6.1, so some ways of parsing won't work for me, like SwiftyJSON.

On internet i only can find the way to send String , but not JSON, or if i found something it won't work.

I'm beginner in iOS and it would really help me if someone can explain me how to do it.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: nsjsonserialization should be good, if you put your JSON-formatted string, I might be able to help more

Comment: @WilliamKinaan well, i have to take string from login text field, and parse to JSON so it would be optional

Comment: a) Update your Xcode, it's free. b) Give an example of your problem and expected output

Comment: @CodeDifferent a)i can't, im using the virtual machine. b)I want when i click on the login button, to parse string(username, pass) from text field, and then send the JSON to server. Do i need to put the code with parsing and sending only under the action of the button login or i have to change another file more?

Answer (score 0):

If you have JSON String convert to NSData object.Check the data object before sending to an external server if data is valid JSON format or not by using NSJSONSerialization.I am giving sample code to how can check JSON Data valid or not.

suppose you String is like this,

```
let jsonString = "{\"device\":\"iPhone 6\",\"OS\":\"iOS 9\",\"name\":\"Apple\"}"
        let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        do {
            let responseData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            if responseData != nil { // valid JSON
                //Now pass data object to server
            }

        } catch {
            NSLog("ERROR when parse JSON")
        }
```